# Hibernate SQL - Can't get an interval from table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I'm trying to get an interval through an operation with Timestamps from a table but I'm getting a "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111"
The code is like this:

```
SELECT TS_FINISH - TS_START FROM TABLE
```

Where TS_FINISH and TS_START are Timestamps

Comment: You are substracting two dates. If you wnat to select certain rows you have to use `WHERE`.

Comment: does jdbc/java have an interval?  that query should work, maybe if it was more obvious to java, like cast(ts_finish - ts_start as interval).  If that doesn't work, cast it to text like cast(ts_finish - ts_start as text).

Comment: Solved this casting the result to a text.

Answer (score 0):

I used a function from my DBMS to cast the result to a text.
Unfortunately there is no hql function that does it.